# Cannot commit android "gen" folder to Git

Tags: android, eclipse, git

I am using EGit in eclipse to provide Git support for an Android project I am working on. The problem is that after committing my project to the local repository I realized that the "gen" folder was not getting committed. As a result of this when I try to open the project on another machine after getting the latest source from the Git repository I keep getting the following error:

> ERROR: Unable to open class file D:\CodeRep\POCs\Java\Android\Sudoku\gen\org\blah\example\R.java: No such file or directory

Why can't I commit the "gen" folder to Git from Eclipse ? Everything gets committed just fine so I can push it to the remote repository.

Comment: You shouldn't commit the `gen/` folder. I think you have to use `clean` or some other eclipse function on your project instead.

Comment: Android tools 8 changed that to not allowing gen files to be included by default

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You shouldn't be commiting the `gen` folder; it contains generated code and doesn't belong in source control. You should be recreating it on the machine you pull the source code on with either an Eclipse "Project -> Clean" or a command line "`ant clean`" if you're using the build scripts.

Answer (score 3):

This is a file of generated code, you would normally only be commit sources to git.

You probably need to clean your project when you check it out, perhaps you've got some other object files mistakenly included in the commit so it looks like it's already been built.

Answer (score 3):

It shouldn't be necessary to commit the "gen" directory to git as everything in it should be automatically generated based upon content elsewhere in your source.  In fact, the "gen" directory may have been added to your .gitignore by the Android SDK.