# Android and version control systems, commit gen folder or put on ignore list?

Tags: android, svn, git, mercurial, cvs

there has already been some discussion about the problems the gen folder causes together with version control systems (SVN, CVS, Git etc). But what is still unclear for me is, should it be commited or put on the ignore list?
What is the recommended way?

thanks!

Comment: Good answer to the question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370668/cannot-commit-android-gen-folder-to-git

Comment: See also https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Android.gitignore

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You shouldn't store `/gen` folder in any version control system (no matter SVN, CVS, Git or anything else). Contents of the folder are generated automatically so it just makes no sense to keep track of the changes.

Comment: ok, i should not store it, but should i put it also on the ignore list?

Comment: @clamp I'd say yes, put it onto the ignore list cause that prevents anybody else from accidental storing of the folder into a repo.